# Collecting user and node locations seperate or combined?

Tags: database, entities, location

In my drupal site i like to have the location of users stored as well as the location of nodes.
To store these locations i am using Geofield in combination with adressfield.
Adressfield collects the postalcode. Geofield codes them in points.

Would it be better to store the locations of nodes and users apart from each other or together:

Meaning storing the user locations in one set of fields: 
Geo field A Postal adress A
And the nodes in Geo field B and Postal adress B?

Or should i just collect both the users and nodes with one set of fields:
Postal adress A and Geo field A for both users and nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other things being equal, it is better to reuse the fields. This simplifies the schema. Neither a postal address field nor a Geo field are likely to change in the future, never mind change differently for nodes and users.